# Table Background Image Displaying in Front of Table

Tags: html, css

After adding a background image to my table, the image is displaying over the table and the contents of the table are hidden. Why is this? HTML and CSS code is below:

```css
.muscles_worked {
  background-image: url(images/dumbbell.png);
  border: 1px dashed black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table class="muscles_worked">
  <caption>Muscles Worked in this Program</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Part of Body</th>
      <th>Day(s)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Legs</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Friday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Core</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thursday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Friday</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you post some code about the html you are using or pseudo version?

Answer (score 0):

A better way might be to set the table in a div and set the background on that.

```css
div.muscles_worked {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/700/500?image=13');
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.muscles_worked > table {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div class="muscles_worked">
  <table>
    <caption>Muscles Worked in this Program</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Part of Body</th>
        <th>Day(s)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Legs</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Friday</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Core</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thursday</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Friday</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: I edited it with a picture and it seems to work fine. Is there some other style you are applying to the table that might be doing this?